# Forcing https:// through htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, redirect, https

I'm very new to coding in general so please forgive me for my ignorance in the subject. I understand that their is a few questions similar to this, but none have seemed to work for me. Useful information is always welcome please due you're best to explain everything to me even if it seems a bit excessive because I'm fairly uneducated in theses particular subjects.

Here is my entire htaccess file located in my root forum directory.

```html
RewriteOptions inherit

RewriteEngine on

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /forums/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule \.(jpeg|jpg|gif|png)$ /forums/public/404.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /forums/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^perspectiverp\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.perspectiverp\.com$
RewriteRule ^home$ "https\:\/\/www\.perspectiverp\.com\/forums\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^perspectiverp\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.perspectiverp\.com$
RewriteRule ^Home$ "https\:\/\/www\.perspectiverp\.com\/forums\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^perspectiverp\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.perspectiverp\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.perspectiverp\.com\/forums\/" [R=301,L]
```

My site will always connect to the website through https:// unless it is being directly told to do otherwise e.g. http://perspectiverp.com/forums/. My issue is that as my general connection is being directed through https:// users can still connect through http:// which is a major security flaw. I basically need it to be similar to how google has their system to automatically redirect http:// to https:// even if the user attempts to change it in the web address

e.g. http:/ww.google.com/ gets redirected to https:/ww.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl if the user attempts to change it to*http:/ww.google.com/.

As for anyone wanting to know what the forum software is, I'm currently using a Licensed version of Invision Powers Community Suit.

**// UPDATED
First attempt Result was "Webpage has Redirect Loop"**

```
RewriteOptions inherit

RewriteEngine on

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /forums/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule \.(jpeg|jpg|gif|png)$ /forums/public/404.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /forums/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.perspectiverp.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?perspectiverp\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(home)?$ https://www.perspectiverp.com/forums/ [R=301,NC,L]
```

**Second attempt Result was "Webpage has Redirect Loop"**

```
RewriteOptions inherit

RewriteEngine on

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /forums/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule \.(jpeg|jpg|gif|png)$ /forums/public/404.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /forums/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.perspectiverp.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?perspectiverp\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^home$ https://www.perspectiverp.com/forums/ [R=301,NC,L
```

**Third attempt Result was "Webpage has Redirect Loop"**

```
RewriteOptions inherit

RewriteEngine on

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /forums/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule \.(jpeg|jpg|gif|png)$ /forums/public/404.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /forums/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.perspectiverp.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^perspectiverp\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.perspectiverp\.com$
RewriteRule ^home$ "https\:\/\/www\.perspectiverp\.com\/forums\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^perspectiverp\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.perspectiverp\.com$
RewriteRule ^Home$ "https\:\/\/www\.perspectiverp\.com\/forums\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^perspectiverp\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.perspectiverp\.com$
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following just before your last three https:// rewrite rules.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.perspectiverp.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Once everything works as expected change `R` to `R=301` above. Also, notice how the URL in my rewrite rule does not quote and escape any forward slashes as it isn't required.

You can also replace your last three rules with just this one:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?perspectiverp\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(home)?$ https://www.perspectiverp.com/forums/ [R=301,NC,L]
```

The `NC` flag makes the rule case-insensitive so `home` and `Home` both will match. The `?` makes the preceding group `()` optional; so the `RewriteCond` works with both `www` and without it, and the `RewriteRule` matches on `/` as well.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't seem to work as I got a "This webpage has a redirect loop" after attempting to use that bit of code.

Comment: Try again with `RewriteRule ^home$ ...` i.e. drop the `?`

Comment: After updating it to that I'm still getting a webpage has redirect error

Comment: Please update your question with how your htaccess looks after all the changes.

Answer (score 0):

I forced https:// through a reverse proxy server (Cloudflare) and was able to force my website to accept https:// traffic only.